# PayPal IPN post array missing values

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I'm trying to receive the IPN data from a simple PAY request using chained payments however when I try to access the post array through $_POST its missing key/value pairs.

I know that all of the data is being sent over because I can receive it all (as an array 'string' separated by ampersands) by using the `file_get_contents("php://input")` function.

The string being returned looks something this this:

> transaction[0].is_primary_receiver=true&transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn=6MD****55453N&log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction=false&transaction[0].receiver=m***r@live.co.uk&action_type=PAY...

When accessing the data through $_POST, it omits

```
transaction => array( 
                     array(
                         is_primary_receiver => true, 
                         id_for_sender_txn => 6MD...)
                         )
                    )
```

why is it acting this way?

If it can't be avoided, is there a way to turn the array string into a proper multidimensional array? I've tried using 
`explode('&', $array)` but I get left with key/value pairs such as `transaction(0).is_primary_receiver => true` which is obviously not the way the data is intended to be stored.

Thanks